# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'SquarePad' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

Tags: python, pytorch

I have seen other posts having the same problem and all of them were multiprocessing problems and had something to do with pool. But I'm not doing any multiprocessing. The same file was running on Google Collab, but giving me this error on Jupyter Notebook.

SquarePad is a user defined class

```
class SquarePad:
    def __call__(self, image):
        max_wh = max(image.size)
        p_left, p_top = [(max_wh - s) // 2 for s in image.size]
        p_right, p_bottom = [max_wh - (s+pad) for s, pad in zip(image.size, [p_left, p_top])]
        padding = (p_left, p_top, p_right, p_bottom)
        return transforms.functional.pad(image, padding, 0, 'constant')
```

This is where I'm calling SquarePad()

```
from torchvision.transforms.transforms import RandomPerspective
data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        SquarePad(),
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(input_size),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.RandomPerspective(distortion_scale=0.5, p=0.5),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(input_size),
        transforms.CenterCrop(input_size),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
}

#print(data_transforms)

print("Initializing Datasets and Dataloaders...")

# Create training and validation datasets

image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x), data_transforms[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
# Create training and validation dataloaders
dataloaders_dict = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4) for x in ['train', 'val']}
class_names = image_datasets['train'].classes

# Detect if we have a GPU available
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "CPU")
```

This is where I'm getting the error

```
def imshow(inp, title=None):
    """Imshow for Tensor."""
    inp = inp.numpy().transpose((1, 2, 0))
    mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
    std = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    inp = std * inp + mean
    inp = np.clip(inp, 0, 1)
    plt.imshow(inp)
    if title is not None:
        plt.title(title)
    plt.pause(0.001)  # pause a bit so that plots are updated


# Get a batch of training data
inputs, classes = next(iter(dataloaders_dict['train']))

# Make a grid from batch
out = torchvision.utils.make_grid(inputs)

imshow(out, title=[class_names[x] for x in classes])
```

The complete error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/anubhav/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "/Users/anubhav/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'SquarePad' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Can anyone explain? I don't usually Jupyter Notebook, so I'm not familiar.

Comment: which line is causing the error?

Comment: You need to `create an instance of the class`.

Comment: @James I ran it again commenting out some lines. Turns out is the one with iter(dataloaders_dict['train'])

Comment: @D.L why was it running fine on Google Collab?

Comment: @D.L also, the function has a __call__ method which makes the class act like a function. Got the code from here: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/pytorch+pad+to+square

Comment: @AnubhabGuha,  you make a good point.  I just didnt see the instance which was the first thing that i looked for, but you are correct there.